# How to convert R.color to Color?

Tags: java, android, colors

Android has 2 types of colors:  [R.color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html)  and [color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)
Layout uses `R.color` (I need `holo_blue_light: 17170450 (0x01060012)`)

but functions (such as setColor()) have the other type of input int (i.e. `CYAN: -16711681 (0xff00ffff)`).

Negation of `R.color` returns incorrect colors. What should I do to convert them?

Comment: see in import area you have import `android.R;` remove that one it will work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since  `getResources().getColor` is now deprecated, you can use:

`ContextCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.idOfColour)`

**old answer**

Use

```
 getResources().getColor(R.color.idOfColour);
```

it returns the `int` color you are looking for. If the colour comes with Android you can get its id with `android.R.color.colourId`

Comment: deprecated, and the whole api of converting from R.color to color code #xxxxxx, is cumbersome to the extent that it seems much better to just hardcode the color code. Why is it so complex?

Comment: @carl thanks for pointing it out. It is not complex. The reason beyond the deprecation  is that the color can be styled with the Context't theme.

Comment: Well, not complex when you know it, but prior to that. There are many threads around on this function that should be super easy, but are instead another three in the garden of Android timethiefs. Sorry for the harsh verdict :-) I suggest the obvious solution should be an agregated level that can accept R.color as input parameter. Would have saved us time.

Comment: An int is an int. How would you distinguish between an int resource and an int color?

Answer (score 3):

1. Color from resources you get through

   > getResources().getColor(R.color.color_id);
2. Color that you had saved from a view (say background color or text color), which will look like your second example, you may get through

> Color.parseColor(String color)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 6 july 2016**

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590927/3244382

Answer (score 1):

Why dont  try to pars color in fowling way

```
int colorCode = Color.parseColor("#ffffff") ;
setColor(colorCode) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

one more thing I would like to add

```
int color_int = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
Color colorName = new Color(color_int );
```

you can use `colorName`  as you want

Comment: Doesn't work for me. There doesn't seem to be a Color initializer with int.