# getColor(int id) deprecated on Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23)

Tags: android, android-resources, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-mnc

The `Resources.getColor(int id)` method has been deprecated.

```
@ColorInt
@Deprecated
public int getColor(@ColorRes int id) throws NotFoundException {
    return getColor(id, null);
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)

Comment: With this method mentioned above: getColor(context, R.color.your_color); It is not clear how to get the "context". It won't work by just putting context there in my case, android studio 3.2. I find this works for me. .setTextColor(Color.RED).

Answer (score 1465, accepted):

Starting from Android Support Library 23,

a new [getColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int)) method has been added to `ContextCompat`.

Its description from the official JavaDoc:

> Returns a color associated with a particular resource ID
>
> Starting in M, the returned color will be styled for the specified Context's theme.

So, **just call**:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

You can check the `ContextCompat.getColor()` [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/57f7e35572a20b6ff4bd99fb714e2efcbf8023bb/compat/src/main/java/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java#L416).

Comment: This looks like the solution, but what are we supposed to do when we get an error "Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here"? As far as I can tell it's probably because Lint does not recognise the new API of the Support Library, so maybe just adding an annotation @SuppressWarnings("ResourceAsColor") is the way to go? I don't like it much though.

Comment: Hi @Stan, can you please provide the code snippet with the method call that triggers the "ResourceAsColor" Lint?

Comment: "int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange);" and then "span = new ForegroundColorSpan(color);". The word that gets underlined in red is "color" where I pass it to "new ForegroundColorSpan()".

Comment: @Stan I've just tried on my PC and it isn't giving off that warning. I'm using Android Studio 2.1 Preview 1 and Support Library 23.2.1. What's your setup?

Comment: I'm using the same Android Studio, tried Support library 23.1.1 and 23.2.1. Additionally, I'm building on Mac, Android Studio runs with jdk1.7.0_79.jdk for the IDE itself, and also for building the project (by default it uses Java 1.6 for the IDE on Mac). I don't know the version of Lint or how to check it but I'm starting to think the reason is elsewhere.

Comment: @Stan same setup here. Don't know what else it might be, sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106481/discussion-between-stan-and-araks).

Comment: Inspecting the ContextCompat.getColor(...), you don't need to check programmatically for the Build version because that method already does for you.

Comment: @MonicaLabbao If you read carefully the answer you'll see that the code that checks the build version is actually the ContextCompat source code...!

Comment: @araks yeah that's what I said. That's what I saw when I inspected the source code. Anyway, let's join the chat if you want to discuss this.

Comment: @MonicaLabbao oh... sorry, I misunderstood your comment! :)

Comment: This isn't working for me. How do you use this new way to get the color if your app supports lower than API 23? The `getContext()` in my code is underlined in red in Android Studio because the lowest API my app supports is 16.

Comment: @ShadowGod this works all the way down to API 4, if your getContext() is underlined in red then there's another problem... What does the IDE suggest you if you leave the mouse over the error for a couple of seconds?

Comment: @araks thanks, I got it working, it's because it was in a fragment

Comment: @ShadowGod I also got a red line, I guess I'm missing an import? How did you get rid of it?

Comment: ContextCompatApi23 this mark error supossed you reference ContextCompat

Comment: For those who don't want to use ContextCompat simply use `Context.getColor(int  id)`.

Comment: But this ContextCompat returns a color id right? So places where a Color is expected are we suppose to generate the color like new Color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color)) ?

Comment: I don't get what's the use of the "theme". Are there any examples?

Comment: where does context comes from? android studio suggest to use Use getColor(int, Theme) instead.

Answer (score 516):

tl;dr:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)
```

Explanation:

You will need to use [ContextCompat.getColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getcolor), which is part of the Support V4 Library (it will work for all the previous APIs).

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)
```

If you don't already use the Support Library, you will need to add the following line to the `dependencies` array inside your app `build.gradle` (note: *it's optional if you already use the appcompat (V7) library*):

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0' # or any version above
```

If you care about themes, the documentation specifies that:

> Starting in M, the returned color will be styled for the specified
>   Context's theme

Comment: This should be the selected as correct answer. Because in the given link of Android Docs, it say "_Starting in `M`, the returned color will be styled for the specified Context's theme._"

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

Comment: @G O'Rilla As you can see in the documentation, the `ContextCompat` class comes from SupportV4. AppcompatV7 works too as it relies on SupportV4. As they say on the [Support Library documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), `This library depends on the v4 Support Library. If you are using Ant or Eclipse, make sure you include the v4 Support Library as part of this library's classpath.`. So it makes sense not to put `AppcompatV7` in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Melvin, here is my example if of use:
        
        int colorTwitterBlue = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_twitter_blue);
        composeTweetAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(colorTwitterBlue);
        composeTweetAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(colorTwitterBlue);

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, the least you can do is at least write a comment on what's the issue is…

Comment: @Melvin. What exactly does it mean the the 'color will be styled to the specified Context's theme'. Sounds like one can define different colors for the same color id depending on the theme. How is this done exactly?

Comment: What's the use of the theme, though?

Answer (score 51):

I don't want to include the Support library just for *getColor*, so I'm using something like

```
public static int getColorWrapper(Context context, int id) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return context.getColor(id);
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        return context.getResources().getColor(id);
    }
}
```

I guess the code should work just fine, and the deprecated `getColor` cannot disappear from API < 23.

**And this is what I'm using in Kotlin:**

```
/**
 * Returns a color associated with a particular resource ID.
 *
 * Wrapper around the deprecated [Resources.getColor][android.content.res.Resources.getColor].
 */
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
@ColorInt
fun getColorHelper(context: Context, @ColorRes id: Int) =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) context.getColor(id) else context.resources.getColor(id);
```

Comment: Looking at the source code, this is exactly how the support library does it. I target API >= 21 so I don't want to include a full jar for these few lines. Note that you can suppress the warning in Android Studio by adding "//noinspection deprecation" above the deprecated call. And use an Activity context, not an Application context, or you might lose theme information.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, although support library can be more future proof choice, I do agree that if this is the only reason you include the support library for, you better off including these couple of lines.

Answer (score 31):

In Android Marshmallow many methods are deprecated.

For example, to get color use

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name);
```

Also to get drawable use

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.drawble_name);
```

Comment: where does the variable context come from? do i have to initialize it? I can't get it to work. To me it seem like Androind has a long way to go; it blows my f mind how much I am struggling to get a f color from a xml resource!! Wow

Answer (score 31):

For all the Kotlin users out there:

```
context?.let {
    val color = ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.colorPrimary)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually should be `val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)`.  The variable "it" could be anything, but it needs to be a __Context__.

Comment: `it` is in this case the `context`, since I use `context?.let {` to check if the `context` is not null. The function `getColor()` only accepts a non-null context. Read more here about `let` and how to use it: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#let

Answer (score 9):

In Kotlin, you can do:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.stage_hls_fallback_snackbar)
```

if requireContext() is accessible from where you are calling the function. I was getting an error when trying

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.stage_hls_fallback_snackbar)
```

Answer (score 7):

in activity  used ContextCompat

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)
```

in Adaper

```
private Context context;


context.getResources().getColor()
```

Answer (score 4):

In Your RecyclerView  in Kotlin

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(t: YourObject, listener: OnItemClickListener.YourObjectListener) = with(itemView) {
        textViewcolor.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.colorPrimary))
        textViewcolor.text = t.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your **current min. API level is 23, you can simply use `getColor()`** like we are using to get string resources by `getString()`:

```
//example
textView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.green));
// if `Context` is not available, use with context.getColor()
```

You can constraint for API Levels below 23:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    textView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.green));
} else {
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
}
```

but to keep it simple, you can do like below as accepted answer:

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green))
```

From [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources).

From [ContextCompat AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat).

From [ContextCompat Support](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat)

Answer (score 2):

The best equivalent is using `ContextCompat.getColor` and `ResourcesCompat.getColor` . I made some extension functions for quick migration:

```
@ColorInt
fun Context.getColorCompat(@ColorRes colorRes: Int) = ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)

@ColorInt
fun Fragment.getColorCompat(@ColorRes colorRes: Int) = activity!!.getColorCompat(colorRes)

@ColorInt
fun Resources.getColorCompat(@ColorRes colorRes: Int) = ResourcesCompat.getColor(this, colorRes, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getColor(Resources, int, Theme)` method of the `ResourcesCompat` from the Android Support Library.

```
int white = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.white, null);
```

I think it reflect better your question than the `getColor(Context, int)` of the `ContextCompat` since you ask about `Resources`. Prior to API level 23, the theme will not be applied and the method calls through to `getColor(int)` but you'll not have the deprecated warning. The theme also may be `null`.

Comment: If you pass null as Theme argument, the returned color will NOT be styled for the current theme. So it might be incorrect.

Comment: @araks Isn't it the same as the deprecated call though? After all, you get the Resources instance in both cases, and not the Context.

Comment: @androiddeveloper they've deprecated the call exactly for that reason: to avoid loading non themed resources.
If you pass null you invalidate all the code migration effort to fix this deprecation and expose yourself to the risk of loading non themed resources (mainly drawables) without any clear indication on why they're not working as intended.
So you should alway provide a Theme instance from your current Activity/Fragment or use the ContextCompat.get* methods.

Comment: @araks You mean the cases that drawables have "?attr/" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need the resources, use [`parseColor(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)): 

 `Color.parseColor("#cc0066")`

Answer (score 0):

I got frustrated too. My need was very straightforward. All I wanted was the ARGB color from the resources, so I wrote a simple static method.

```
protected static int getARGBColor(Context c, int resId)
        throws Resources.NotFoundException {

    TypedValue color = new TypedValue();
    try {
        c.getResources().getValue(resId, color, true);
    }
    catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        throw(new Resources.NotFoundException(
                  String.format("Failed to find color for resourse id 0x%08x",
                                resId)));
    }
    if (color.type != TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB8) {
        throw(new Resources.NotFoundException(
                  String.format(
                      "Resourse id 0x%08x is of type 0x%02d. Expected TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB8",
                      resId, color.type))
        );
    }
    return color.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getColor(int)`: This method was deprecated in API level 23.
Use `getColor(int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme)` instead.

**My try for `minSDK = 21`:**

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                resources.getColor(R.color.rippelColor, null)
            } else {
                resources.getColor(R.color.rippelColor)
            }
```

[Official Reference from developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getColor(int))