# getColor Error in API Level 23

Tags: android

`getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name)` is now deprecated in API Level 23 but can work by adding a Color Theme as a second parameter like

`getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name, Theme)`
according to the new documentation but when I pass in null value for the Theme like

`getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name, null)`
my app crashes. Maybe I am missing something in my understanding. Please help, thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the crash stack trace?

Comment: Are you actually running an API level 23 device? because if not, then that method would not be available and you'd get a NoSuchMethodError

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The old method is deprecated starting in API 23, and the new method only exists in API 23+. You are attempting to call the new method on a device running API <23.

You can either perform an API level check and call the appropriate method, or you can use `ContextCompat.getColor(Context, int)` from the support-v4 library.

Answer (score 10):

Try this..

```
int color = Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.color.color_name));
```

instead

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name);
```

Comment: This method is great. It may not be optimal, but it's straightforward and works. Best of all, it gets me out of the science project getting color from a resource has become.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590927/3484905), you can use [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html) as follows:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to set color from adapter class

```
View view=super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue_100));
```