# setTextColor on Android 5.1

Tags: android, text, colors, textview, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Why only on Android 5.1 or above `setTextColor` method doesn't works?

```
TextView TextView32 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView32);
TextView32.setText(String.valueOf(LikesNumber2));
SendLikes2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.likeyes);
TextView32.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Strange, but on Android 4.4 and above 30 mobile phones with variable versions textColor changes. Where is a mistake?

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout                
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="7dp">

     <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/SendLikesHe"
            android:background="@drawable/likezero"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView32"
            android:textColor="#fffb0049"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SendLikesHe" />

     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Like"
            android:id="@+id/textView67_onn"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/SendLikesHe"
            android:textColor="#FB0049" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: strange. its working for me android 5.1.1

Comment: Use `ContextCompat.getColor()`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31590927/4908802).

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
TextViewObj.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Color_Name));
```

Or use **ContextCompat**

```
TextViewObj.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.Color_Name));
```

[getColor(int id) deprecated on Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23/31590927#31590927)

Hope this helps .

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i think problem is in ImageView. It can impose the text (i dont know how i can say it in english - something like "you cann't see text because imageview on them"). So problem isn't solved

Answer (score 0):

You are trying

```
 TextView32.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

which is `WHITE` color. Is your background color not a `white`??

Try to set background color gray(#808080) or other and set color as,

```
TextViewObj.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Color_Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#DD1515"));
```

Above line should work fine. tested in 4.4, 5.1, 6.0