# App crashes while trying to change status bar color

Tags: android

Im using the following code to change the color of status bar. When I try to do so, the app crashes.

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: could you please post the logcat..

Answer (score 0):

`getColor(Color.BLUE)` getColor takes a Resource identifier i.e. `R.color.blue` not a static `Color` constant

Ref:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)

> The desired resource identifier, as generated by the aapt tool. This integer encodes the package, type, and resource entry. The value 0 is an invalid identifier.

---

This method is also deprecated now and recommended you use the compatibility `getColor`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590927/413127

Answer (score 0):

put this code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textblue));
}
```

Comment: how to use it with non activity class