# getRecources method error [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to use this part of the Code to "import" colors from the colors.xml:

```
extraHeightView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar));
```

but Android Studio always say:

```
Cannot resolve method 'getRecources'
```

The mystery is that in another scripts its work:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar));
```

but it´s the same...

I think i have to import something in the beginning of the script, but I don´t know what I have to import.

Here are the imports of the skript which doesn´t work:

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.StateListAnimator;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Outline;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewOutlineProvider;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.telegram.PhoneFormat.PhoneFormat;
import org.telegram.messenger.AndroidUtilities;
import org.telegram.messenger.AnimationCompat.AnimatorListenerAdapterProxy;
import org.telegram.messenger.AnimationCompat.AnimatorSetProxy;
import org.telegram.messenger.AnimationCompat.ObjectAnimatorProxy;
import org.telegram.messenger.AnimationCompat.ViewProxy;
import org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader;
import org.telegram.messenger.BuildVars;
import org.telegram.messenger.FileLoader;
import org.telegram.messenger.FileLog;
import org.telegram.messenger.LocaleController;
import org.telegram.messenger.MediaController;
import org.telegram.messenger.MessageObject;
import org.telegram.messenger.MessagesController;
import org.telegram.messenger.MessagesStorage;
import org.telegram.messenger.NotificationCenter;
import org.telegram.messenger.R;
import org.telegram.messenger.UserConfig;
import org.telegram.messenger.UserObject;
import org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager;
import org.telegram.tgnet.RequestDelegate;
import org.telegram.tgnet.SerializedData;
import org.telegram.tgnet.TLObject;
import org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC;
import org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.ActionBar;
import org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.ActionBarMenu;
import org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.ActionBarMenuItem;
import org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.BaseFragment;
import org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.BottomSheet;
import org.telegram.ui.Adapters.BaseFragmentAdapter;
import org.telegram.ui.Cells.CheckBoxCell;
import org.telegram.ui.Cells.EmptyCell;
import org.telegram.ui.Cells.HeaderCell;
import org.telegram.ui.Cells.ShadowSectionCell;
import org.telegram.ui.Cells.TextCheckCell;
import org.telegram.ui.Cells.TextDetailSettingsCell;
import org.telegram.ui.Cells.TextInfoCell;
import org.telegram.ui.Cells.TextSettingsCell;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.AvatarDrawable;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.AvatarUpdater;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.BackupImageView;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.LayoutHelper;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.NumberPicker;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
```

And the imports from the Skript which works:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.telegram.messenger.AndroidUtilities;
import org.telegram.messenger.ContactsController;
import org.telegram.messenger.LocaleController;
import org.telegram.messenger.MediaController;
import org.telegram.messenger.MessagesController;
import org.telegram.PhoneFormat.PhoneFormat;
import org.telegram.messenger.NotificationsController;
import org.telegram.messenger.UserObject;
import org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader;
import org.telegram.messenger.FileLoader;
import org.telegram.messenger.FileLog;
import org.telegram.messenger.NotificationCenter;
import org.telegram.messenger.R;
import org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager;
import org.telegram.tgnet.TLRPC;
import org.telegram.messenger.MessageObject;
import org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.ActionBar;
import org.telegram.ui.ActionBar.ActionBarMenu;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.AvatarDrawable;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.BackupImageView;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.ChatActivityEnterView;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.FrameLayoutFixed;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.LayoutHelper;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.PopupAudioView;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.RecordStatusDrawable;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.SizeNotifierFrameLayout;
import org.telegram.ui.Components.TypingDotsDrawable;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
```

If you have another conclusion to use colors from the colors.xml, write it please down too :D

Please help me and sorry for my english :D

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that error is copy-pasted its just a typo.

`getRecources` should be `getResources`

The only thing you have to worry about importing to use your colours is the 'R' file (com.yourcompany.yourpackage.R). You should also update to the modern method:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.action_bar); //where this is a 'Context'
```

Comment: Not really it just works in one script. In the othe it say: "require:android.content.context", but I import it ... And if i use context instad of this it says: "cannot resolve symbol ..." :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it doesn't work, but it looks like you might have switched the imports "working" vs "not working", as one is missing the required `import android.content.res.Resources;`.

As a side note, this method is deprecated, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23) to check on the new one.

Comment: I already import android.content.res.Recources  ,but the secound way works. Thank you :)