# How to write color id in MainActivity? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to change the button color using this line of code: `button.setTextColor(R.color.erik_secundario)`

But it doesn't work. So I also read about using that:
`getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color)`

And the problem is that i don't know where i need to implement that code to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, not the button color but the button text color.

Comment: `getResources().getColor()` returns the value you want to pass to the `setTextColor()` call, so either just put `getResources().getColor(R.color.erik_secundario)` in `setTextColor()` instead, or assign it to an `int` variable first, and pass that to `setTextColor()`.

Comment: Thanks, i think it's working, but now appears a message that says "getcolor() deprecated in Java". Is there any problem if i'm using kotlin?

Comment: No, it's not that you're using it with Kotlin. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31590714).

Comment: Just saw it, but i don't know what means "context", is there any other option to change text color?

Comment: Your `Activity` is a `Context`. You can just pass `this` or `YourActivity.this`, as needed.

Comment: Okey, I arrived that point: `button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.erik_secundario)`. Now there's another message that calls me to fill `getActivity()`. What should i write inside?

Comment: Why did you write `getActivity()`?

Comment: I saw it on a post, its useless?

Comment: If you're in an `Activity` class, you don't use `getActivity()`. You use `this`, or `YourActivityName.this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you choose `getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color)`, it will show line through which means deprecated. So you have to use `ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white)`. for context parameter, if you are using it in Activity, use `this@YourActivity` and in Fragment, use `context`or `activity`. hope it will help your problem.